# border-bottom showing on top of div

Tags: html, css

I have set a border-bottom but its showing on top for a reason i cant work out.

I have set up a jsfiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/nnEr9/

Comment: Both the below answers will work so I'm not going to reiterate, but I will say you should try using an HTML inspector, such as Firebug. It would instantly show you the box model layout for your elements and point you in the right direction within seconds.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`overflow: hidden` on the header - see
http://jsfiddle.net/thebabydino/nnEr9/1/

The problem is that you've floated the children of your header. Therefore, your header has height zero, as you can see below

[image: screenshot]

[link to fullsize image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UkkO8.jpg)

You fix it with `overflow: hidden` (`overflow: auto` also works).

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `overflow:auto` to the header div. Because you floated the other divs you need to add this to account for the float:

```
#header {
    margin-top: 50px;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #8B0000;
    overflow:auto;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/nnEr9/2/)**.