# 'border-bottom' shows on top of div

Tags: html, css

I have a `border-bottom` property on my `<div>` but the border is appearing on top. I have no floats and `overflow: hidden` won't work!

How can I get the border to show on the bottom of the `<div>`?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Pacifico);
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

.text-title {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #A4A4A4;
}
.name {
  font-family: 'Pacifico', cursive;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 26px;
  top: .5px;
  margin-top: 0px;
  left: 20px;
}
.name a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  transition: .2s color;
}
.name a:hover {
  color: #A47D7D;
}
.links {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  position: absolute;
  top: 23px;
  right: 50px;
}
.links a {
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-right: 20px;
  transition: .2s color;
}
.links a:hover {
  color: #A47D7D;
}
```

```html
<div class="text-title">
  <div class="name">
    <a href="#">georetro</a>
  </div>

  <div class="links">
    <a href="#" id="about">About</a>
    <a href="#" id="portfolio">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="#" id="contact">Contact Us</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="slogan-area"></div>

<div class="about-me"></div>

<div class="portfolio-area"></div>

<div class="contact-us"></div>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/huhfyeoe/)

Comment: I see no `border-bottom` property in the link you provided, nor do I see any border at all. It might help if you also mentioned which browser you're using.

Comment: You might also want to look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10789218/border-bottom-showing-on-top-of-div?rq=1)

Comment: I am using chrome. That's weird

Comment: BTW I looked at that answer before but it didn't help me.

Answer (score 1):

Your inner divs have a position of absolute, so aren't expanding that parent div.  You need to set a height for it if you want the essentially flat parent div to have a bottom and border below the children.